# Remote Config Alternative: Store UI specific parameters

Tags: android, ios, firebase, user-interface, firebase-remote-config

I want to change the UI of ios and android apps without release.

For example, show/hide images, display position, etc.

We thought about distributing these parameters through the backend API that the native app refers to, but since this API is designed as a resource server, it is unnatural to handle parameters that are closely related to the UI, which we want to avoid.

Firebase Remote Config is a better option, but its major disadvantages are that it is difficult to handle data with complex structure, and it is difficult to operate via API.

Is there a better alternative to Firebase Remote Config as a data store suitable for managing parameters closely related to the UI ?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is with a Feature Flag and Remote config service. This is actually the exact reason we started [Flagsmith](https://flagsmith.com/)! As per [this comment](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/36#issuecomment-391630244) from 2017 discussing exactly this requirement with the Firebase platform.

You can use a service like Flagsmith to store code configuration fragments in a format like `json` or `yaml` and then import them into your app via an API at runtime. This is particularly powerful when dealing with mobile applications were you are not able to control when people upgrade your app.

You can also use these tools to roll out features gradually, or run A/B and Multivariate tests with different configurations.